# How to raise 404 as a status code in Serializer Validate function in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

I have written a validate() function inside my serializer. By default, Serializer Errors return 400 as a status code. But I want to return 404. I tried this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyClass
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        current_user = self.context.get("request").user
        user = data.get("user")
        if user!=current_user:
            raise ValidationError({'detail': 'Not found.'}, code=404)
        return data
```

But it still returns 400 as a response in status code.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from view by handling the serializes validation:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyClass
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        current_user = self.context.get("request").user
        user = data.get("user")
        if user != current_user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'detail': 'Not found.'},
                code=404,
            )
        return data


class MyView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MySerializer(
            data=request.data,
            context={'request': request},
        )
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=404)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Alternately you can do it by defining own exception handler:

```
def my_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is not None and response.status_code == 400:
        response.status_code = 404
    return response

class MyView(APIView):
    exception_handler = my_exception_handler

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MySerializer(
            data=request.data, 
            context={'request': request},
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But as you said, if you want to do it from serializer, then you have to define custom exception and raise it from serialize :

```
class NotFoundError(serializers.ValidationError):
    def __init__(self, detail):
        super().__init__(detail, code=404)


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyClass
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, data):
        current_user = self.context.get("request").user
        user = data.get("user")
        if user != current_user:
            raise NotFoundError({'detail': 'Not found.'})
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Django source code that handles validation errors.

```
    def is_valid(self, *, raise_exception=False):
        # This implementation is the same as the default,
        # except that we use lists, rather than dicts, as the empty case.
        assert hasattr(self, 'initial_data'), (
            'Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was '
            'passed when instantiating the serializer instance.'
        )

        if not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
            try:
                self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
            except ValidationError as exc:
                self._validated_data = []
                self._errors = exc.detail
            else:
                self._errors = []

        if self._errors and raise_exception:
            raise ValidationError(self.errors)

        return not bool(self._errors)
```

Django checks for ValidationError, then takes the details from that error object and re-creates with a 400 status code, which is why your code does not work.

So, from your view class, catch the django error and change the status code as shown.

```
class NotesList(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.MyClass.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            return self.create(request)
        except ValidationError as exc:
            exc.status_code = 404
            raise exc
```